# Show Screen Of Android 4.0 Device On Computer

Tags: android, screen-capture, vnc, vnc-server

I'll have to do a presentation soon, for this, I need to show the the application too 10 people at the same time. For this I'd like to display the screen of my Android 4.0 Phone (Galaxy Nexus) on the Computer and all this in live!

For this I tried droid vnc beta - well its a beta and so it didn't work... it only showed me a black sceen on my computer.

are there any other ways, that I can display the screen of my device on my computer. Btw im using win7.

Thx for your help in advance!

best regards

safari

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Galaxy Nexus supports HDMI out. You could plug it straight into a monitor / projector. You can get HDMI > DVI converters if you need that too. The HDMI converter cable can be bought online at Amazon etc, something like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0063J9F6C)

Comment: worked really great! Thank you again!

Answer (score 6):

You might want to try Android Screencast. It works perfectly for me, other than the lack of frame rate. The link is [here](http://code.google.com/p/androidscreencast/)

Comment: i tried this one to, but it has a pritty lame reactionrate

Comment: That's because it's a work in progress, unless you're considering the HDMI solution. It's a free alternative for people who don't want to spend =)

Comment: I'll think i need to spend some money, but thank you anyways!

Answer (score 2):

Please try [Android Screenshots, Screen Capture, Screen Cast](http://www.mightypocket.com/2010/08/android-screenshots-screen-capture-screen-cast/)

In such a way it can be used for full screen presentations, automatic screen capture, and screenshot transformations such as scaling and rotating.

Answer (score 2):

Try this app:

VMLite VNC Server, works well on non rooted devices, you can connect multiple VNC viewers, or use html to show the screens.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vmlite.vncserver&hl=en

Comment: tried it out. dosn't work that well on jelly bean..

Comment: we have lots of jelly bean users, and all works well, you may want to try latest build

Comment: probably i'll give it a kick somewhen for the moment i got my cable to connect it directly to a beamer or TV. But thx anyway!

Comment: how to develop this app can you guide me @huisinro

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to screen it over a wifi and it's a new mobile such as the Nexus 4 you can use it's [Miracast support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miracast).

Here a link for a youtube video on how it's done:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DwvYrv2s9Kk

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you want to show. If it's your own application that you developped, you can use the Android SDK to show directly the application on your computer in a virtual device. It has the advantage of showing the cursor which represent your finger. If it's for other purposes, then refer to the other answers. (ScreenCast works good for me)

Comment: yes, i know but the emulator is pritty slow...

Comment: It all depends on your computer and how you defined your virtual device. Just go in the properties of your virtual device and add memory or boost the other stats.